# How to add element in second array only?

Tags: javascript, arrays

> Array 1

```
var arr1 = ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"];
```

Now I moved this array to another array.

```
var arr2 = arr1;
arr2.push("lmn");
```

Now when I alert arr1, It is showing `"abc", "pqr", "xyz", "lmn"`
but I pushed "lmn" in arr2?

I don't want to change arr1 values.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the spread operator, it will fix the problem. It will look something like this`var arr2 = [...arr1]`

Answer (score 0):

You have reference to the same array. You can either use `spread operator` or `slice` for cloning the value of array.

```js
var arr1 = ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"];

var arr2 = [...arr1]; // or  arr1.slice(0)

arr2.push('imn');

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```